# Uncaught Error: Unknown provider: $templateRequestProvider <- $templateRequest <- $modal

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

**Hello Stackoverflowers ;)**

I struggle for a bit of time on this particular problem concerning the bootstrap.ui modal:

> Uncaught Error: Unknown provider: $templateRequestProvider <- $templateRequest <- $modal

I tried already to define a provider but I can't get it to work properly.

This is my app.js:

```
var app = angular.module('stelping', ['ui.bootstrap']).
config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
        when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'pages/home.html',
            controller: HomeCtrl,
            activetab: 'home'
        }).
        when('/notentool', {
            templateUrl: 'pages/notentool.html',
            controller: NotentoolCtrl,
            activetab: 'notentool'
        }).
        when('/lerngruppe', {
            templateUrl: 'pages/lerngruppe.html',
            controller: LerngruppenCtrl,
            activetab: 'lerngruppe'
        }).
        when('/raumreservierung', {
            templateUrl: 'pages/raumreservierung.html',
            controller: RaumreservierungCtrl,
            activetab: 'raumreservierung'
        }).
        when('a', function() {
            return {
                restrict: 'E',
                link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
                    if(attrs.ngClick || attrs.href === '' || attrs.href === '#'){
                        elem.on('click', function(e){
                            e.preventDefault();
                        });
                    }
            }
        }}).
        when('/registrieren', {
            templateUrl: 'pages/registrieren.html',
            controller: RegistrierungsCtrl,
            activetab: 'registrieren'
        }).
        otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' });
}]).run(['$rootScope', '$modal', '$log', '$http', '$browser', '$timeout', "$route", function ($scope, $modal, $log, $http, $browser, $timeout, $route) {

    $scope.$on("$routeChangeSuccess", function (scope, next, current) {
        $scope.part = $route.current.activetab;
    });


}]);

app.config(['$locationProvider', function($location) {
    $location.hashPrefix('!');
}]);
```

And this is my controller.js (partially only the two new Ctrls):

```
function LerngruppenCtrl($scope, $modal, $log) {
$scope.buildings = [ 1, 5, 6 ];
$scope.rooms = [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 ];
$scope.currentBuilding = 1;
$scope.currentRoom = 0;
$scope.setRoom = function(room) {
    $scope.currentRoom = room;
}
$scope.setBuilding = function(building) {
    $scope.currentBuilding = building;
}
$scope.imgChanger = function() {
    return $scope.currentBuilding+"_"+$scope.currentRoom;
};
$scope.class = "hidden";

$scope.open = function (size) {

    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
        templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
        controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',
        size: size
    });
    modalInstance.result.then(function () {
        $log.info('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
    });
};
}

function ModalInstanceCtrl($scope, $modalInstance) {
    $scope.cancel = function () {
        $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
    };
}
```

Comment: My guess is that your versions of angular and ui.bootstrap are incompatible. Are they both latest? If not, which versions are each on?

Comment: Do you include the UI Bootstrap js files in your HTML file? I've often run into these errors, where it turns out that I simply forgot to load up the file.

Comment: true that. I totally forgot to check this... well angular is 1.1.15 and bootstrap ui is 0.13.0. changing angular to the newest will lead me to a new problem: Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.15/$injector/modulerr?p0=stelping&p1=Error%…gleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.3.15%2Fangular.min.js%3A38%3A135). Yes aaron I do but this load normally as it should so does the dev tools tell me

Comment: added ngRoute and solved the problem. One is now remaining: Error: [ng:areq] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.15/ng/areq?p0=LerngruppenCtrl&p1=not%20aNaNunction%2C%20got%20undefined

Comment: Looks like something with how you're invoking the controller. While you can just declare global functions as controllers, it's better to use `.controller`. Are you perhaps doing `ng-controller="LerngruppenCtrl"`? If its a global function, you'll need parens, `ng-controller="LerngruppenCtrl()"`.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

That error is due to a mismatch between the versions of `ui.bootstrap` and `angular`. `ui.bootstrap` .13 depends on 1.3x, .12 depended on 1.2x.

Comment: I didn't see it in [Change Log](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#0130-2015-05-02), they should 've put this info.

Answer (score 1):

I also have same problem.
I solved it by using latest version of angularjs, ui-bootstrap
I have used these version:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.4/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.4/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/0.13.3/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I had an issue which was solved with the four lines you wrote, thanks , keep helping

Answer (score 0):

I also has this problem,I use angular 1.2.28 and ui.bootstrap 0.12.1,If I use Jetty run my App on Chrome ,Then console will  display 'Unknown provider: $templateRequestProvider <- $templateRequest <- $modal',But If I run my App on Safari will not display error.